# Why does Fluentd metric fluentd_output_status_emit_records counter decreases occasionally causing derivative to go negative

Tags: metrics, fluentd

I am trying to use `prometheus.metrics.fluentd_output_status_emit_records` metric exposed by fluentd's @prometheus_output_monitor plugin to detect any intervals of 0 data. As per the documentation it's metric type is counter which means it should always go up unless pod/fluentd is restarted. But I am seeing it's value decrease occasionally and I am trying to find out what can cause it to go down?
In the fluent log I see some errors related to parsing of data but I am thinking that those errors shouldn't cause the counter to reset since Fluentd is just supposed to drop records. Any insight will be highly appreciated.
Following is the sample I am using to expose metrics from Fluentd:

```
<source>
  @type prometheus_output_monitor
  interval 10
  <labels>
    hostname ${hostname}
  </labels>
</source>
```

Fluentd errors:

```
2021-04-01 15:12:39 +0000 [warn]: #0 send an error event to @ERROR: error_class=TypeError error="no implicit conversio[0/1877]ent::EventTime into String" location="/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-4.3.3/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch.rb:559:in `parse'" tag="Fluent::ElasticsearchOutput::TimeParser.error" time=2021-04-01 15:12:39.665600025 +0000
2021-04-01 15:12:39 +0000 [warn]: #0 send an error event to @ERROR: error_class=TypeError error="no implicit conversion of Fluent::EventTime into String" location="/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch-4.3.3/lib/fluent/plugin/out_elasticsearch.rb:559:in `parse'" tag="Fluent::ElasticsearchOutput::TimeParser.error" time=2021-04-01 15:12:39.666391380 +0000
```

Answer (score 0):

I pulled the below info directly from a running Fluentd instance. `fluentd_output_status_emit_records` metric type is `gauge` and *not* `counter`.

```
# TYPE fluentd_output_status_emit_records gauge
# HELP fluentd_output_status_emit_records Current emit records.
fluentd_output_status_emit_records{host="fluentd-29n96",plugin_id="object:2aac8720e794",type="stdout"} 34036.0
fluentd_output_status_emit_records{host="fluentd-29n96",plugin_id="object:3fee46a59dfc",type="forward"} 147200343.0
fluentd_output_status_emit_records{host="fluentd-29n96",plugin_id="object:2aac86a44860",type="null"} 7318.0
```